# Footer sticked to bottom and geting issue with divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with footer, I want it to be at the bottom of the page and it only works when I give the fixed position property. But I don't want the footer to scroll with the screen. I checked similar problems on StackOverflow and CSS sticky footer but I couldn't find the one that works for me.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Polskie znaki-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--Responstywność-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--Arkusz styli-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/superslides.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,200,300,400,700,900,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
        <div id="header">
          <ul class="topnav">
            <li style="padding:5px; margin-right: 50px;"><img src="img/logo.png"></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">STRONA GŁÓWNA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">NASZE PRODUKTY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">KONTAKT</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/burgermenu.png" alt="Rozwiń menu dla wersji responsywnej"></a></li>

            <form>
              <span><input type="text" class="search searchform" placeholder="Szukaj..."></input></span>
            </form>

          </ul>
          <!--SLIDER-->
            <div class="wide-container">
              <div id="slides">
                <ul class="slides-container">
                  <li>
                    <img src="img/slider.jpg" alt="">
                    <h2>Lata doświadczeń
                    </br> &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; i gwarancja profesjonalizmu.</h2>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src="img/slider.jpg" alt="Cinelli">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src="img/slider.jpg" width="1024" height="682" alt="Surly">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src="img/slider.jpg" width="1024" height="683" alt="Cinelli">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src="img/slider.jpg" width="1024" height="685" alt="Affinity">

                  </li>
                </ul>

                <nav class="slides-navigation">
                  <a href="#" class="next"><img src="img/next.png" alt="Następny"></a>
                  <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="img/previous.png" alt="Poprzedni"></a>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
<!--TOGGLE SIDEBAR-->
<!-- =========================
      Sidebar
    ============================== -->
<div id="content">
    <section id="page">
        <main class="middle">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                  <div class="well">
                      <div>
                          <ul class="nav nav-list">
                              <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Zestawy do badań nieniszczących NDT<a href="#"><img id="openicon" src="img/openincon.png" alt="rozwiń"></a></label>
                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                      <li><a href="#">Zmywacz</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Penetrant</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Wywyływacz</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Podkład Biały</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Zawiesina czarnego proszku magnetycznego</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Penetracja fluorescencyjna</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Środki Przeciwodpryskowe<a href="#"><img id="openicon" src="img/openincon.png" alt="rozwiń"></a></label>
                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                      <li><a href="#">Preparat w postaci pasty</a></li>
                                              <li><label class="tree-toggle"><li>Preparaty aerozolowe</li></label>
                                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                                      <li><a href="#">Prep 1</a></li>
                                                      <li><a href="#">Prep 2</a></li>
                                                  </ul>
                                              </li>
                                      <li><label class="tree-toggle"><li>Preparaty w postaci cieczy</li></label>
                                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                                      <li><a href="#">Prep 1</a></li>
                                                      <li><a href="#">Prep 2</a></li>
                                                  </ul>
                                              </li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                               <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Środki trawiące<a href="#"><img id="openicon" src="img/openincon.png" alt="rozwiń"></a></label>
                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                      <li><a href="#">Pasty trawiące</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Płyn trawiący</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Płyn pasywujący PPAS</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Pasta neutralizacyjn PN-1</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                               <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Topniki<a href="#"><img id="openicon" src="img/openincon.png" alt="rozwiń"></a></label>
                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                      <li><a href="#">Topniki do lutów twardych - Boraks</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                               <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Luty twarde<a href="#"><img style="float:right;" src="img/openincon.png" alt="rozwiń"></a></label>
                                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                      <li><a href="#">Spoiwa mosiężne</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Spoiwa aluminiowe</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Spoiwa brązowe i miedziane</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                               <li class="divider"></li>
                               <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Koncentrat biostatyczny GOP<a href="#"><img style="float:right;" src="img/openincon.png" alt="rozwiń"></a></label>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<!--OBRAZKI I TEKST-->

      <div class="blocks">

              <div class="block">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="block">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="block">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="block">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="block">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="block">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""></div>
              </div> 
        </div>


<!--KONTAKT-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="kontakt">
            <div>
              <p>tel.:<span>+48 000 000 000</span></p>
            </div>

            <div>
              <p>e-mail.:<span>topchem@topchem.pl</span></p>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid sidetext">
                  <div class="row-fluid">  

        <h1 class="post-title">&emsp;&emsp; O FIRMIE &emsp;&emsp; </h1>

      <p>Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac. Vestibulum congue nisl magna. Ut vulputate odio id dui convallis in adipiscing libero condimentum. Nunc et pharetra enim. Praesent pharetra, neque et luctus tempor, leo sapien faucibus leo, a dignissim turpis ipsum sed libero. Sed sed luctus purus. Aliquam faucibus turpis at libero consectetur euismod. Nam nunc lectus, congue non egestas quis, condimentum ut arcu. Nulla placerat, tortor non egestas rutrum, mi turpis adipiscing dui, et mollis turpis tortor vel orci. Cras a fringilla nunc. Suspendisse volutpat, eros congue scelerisque iaculis, magna odio sodales dui, vitae vulputate elit metus ac arcu. Mauris consequat rhoncus dolor id sagittis. Cras tortor elit, aliquet quis tincidunt eget, dignissim non tortor.</p>

                </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.post -->

  <!-- /#content --> 


        </main>
    </section>
</div>
<!--STOPKA-->

<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer_container">
   <div class="footer-right">

                <a href="#"><img src="img/Twitter.png"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/facebbok.png"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/googleicon.png"></a>

            </div>

            <div class="footer-left">

                <p class="footer-links">
                    <a href="#">Strona główna</a>

                    <a href="#">Nasze produkty</a>

                    <a href="#">Kontakt</a>

                </p>

            </div>
</div>



<!-- /#
<!--menu SCRIPT-->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--SLIDER SCRIPT-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.superslides.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').superslides({
        inherit_width_from: '.wide-container',
        inherit_height_from: '.wide-container'
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!--NAV SCRIPT-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.tree-toggle').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
});
$(function(){
$('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
})
  </script>




</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
<style>

body {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;


}
html {
  background: #ececec;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}

#page{
background: #ececec;
margin-bottom: 100px;

}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* TOP NAVIGATION */
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #343e5c;

}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #343e5c;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
ul.topnav form {

  float:right;
  margin-right: 40px;

}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #f2f3f4;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav form:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
    ul.topnav.responsive form {
    float: center;
    display: inline;
  }
}

/* SEARCH BAR */

.search { 
  padding:15px 15px 15px 49px;
  margin:3px; 
  background: url('../img/search.png') no-repeat 20px 15px; 
}
.searchform { 

  background-color: #c0dbf3;
  border:none;
}

input[type=text]{
  color:#4f98d7;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* For WebKit browsers */
                color:#4f98d7;
                font-weight:bold;

}
:-moz-placeholder { /* For Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
                color:#4f98d7;
                font-weight:bold;

}
::-moz-placeholder { /* For Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
                color:#4f98d7;
                font-weight:bold;

}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* For Internet Explorer 10+ */
                color:#4f98d7;
                font-weight:bold;

}
/* SLIDER */

    .wide-container {
      height: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
/* TOGGLE SIDEBAR */
.middle {
  max-width: 1300px;
  background: #ececec;
  position: absolute;
  color: #343e5c;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 140px;
  height: auto !important;



}

.row{
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.span3{

  margin: 30px 30px 10px 15px;

}

.well{
  list-style-type: none;


}
#openicon{

  float: right;


}



li.divider{

  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;

}


/* MAIN */
.blocks {

float: right;
width: 70%;

}

.blocks .block {
  display: inline-block;
   margin: 30px 30px 10px 0px;


}

.sidetext{
    float: right;
    max-width: 70%;


  }
.row-fluid{

  margin-right: 20%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1282px) and (max-width:1920px){

   .middle{

       float: center;
      }

.kontakt{
    font-size:10pt;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 325px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;

}


}
@media screen and (min-width:981px) and (max-width:1281px){

  .kontakt{
      width: 285px;
      margin-left: -5px;
      float: left;

  }



}




@media screen and (min-width:681px) and (max-width:980px) {

      .row{
        width: 100%;
      }

      .blocks{
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: -30px;
      }
      .blocks .block {
      display: inline-block;

      }
      .kontakt{
        margin: 20px -10px 20px 10px;
        width: 95%;
      }
.sidetext{
    max-width: 100%;
    float: center;


  }

.row-fluid{

  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}


}
@media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:680px) {

    .row{
        width: 100%;
      }

      .blocks{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 20px 0% 10px 9%;
      }
      .blocks .block {
      display: inline-block;

      }
      .kontakt{
        margin: 20px -10px 20px 10px;
        width: 95%;
      }
      .middle{
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        max-width: 680px;
      }
      .sidetext{
    max-width: 100%;
    float: center;


  }

.row-fluid{

  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:2px) and (max-width:480px){

  html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }

    .row{
        width: 100%;
      }

      .blocks{
        width: 100%;
      }
      .blocks .block {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 18%;

      }
      .kontakt{
        width: 100%;
      }
      .middle{

        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
      .sidetext{
    max-width: 100%;
    float: center;


  }

.row-fluid{

  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
}

/* KONTAKT */

.kontakt{
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;


}

.kontakt span{

   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
   margin-left:auto;


}
/************************************************************************************
CONTENT
*************************************************************************************/

/* post */

.post-title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #445485;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  color: #343e5c;

}

/************************************************************************************
FOOTER
*************************************************************************************/

#footer_container {
    clear: both;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color: #336699;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 35px 40px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #292c2f;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}

#footer_container .footer-left p{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:  #8f9296;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Footer links */

#footer_container p.footer-links{
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:  #ffffff;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

#footer_container p.footer-links a{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:  inherit;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#footer_container .footer-right{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 6px;
  max-width: 180px;
}

#footer_container .footer-right a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color:  #33383b;
  border-radius: 2px;

  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;

  margin-left: 3px;
}

/* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

@media (max-width: 600px) {

  .footer-distributed .footer-left,
  .footer-distributed .footer-right{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .footer-distributed .footer-right{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
  }

  .footer-distributed .footer-left p.footer-links{
    line-height: 1.8;
  }
}


/* IE 6 */
* html #footer_container {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}



</style>
```

Comment: you can give position fixed to footer and by using jquery's window scroll event you can change position of footer to static

Comment: Do you want the footer always stuck to the very bottom of the screen, even when scrolling? Your question isn't very clear. Also, you shouldn't include your entire HTML and CSS code, just the relevant parts.

Comment: Exactly, I want footer to be at the very bottom all the time, even when scrolling. I just thought there might be mistake in other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has a lot of errors.

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="search searchform" placeholder="Szukaj..."></input>
```

Should be self-closing like:

```
<input type="text" class="search searchform" placeholder="Szukaj..." />
```

Also: `</br>` should be `<br />` (also self-closing).

And there's a random `</ul>` at **line 132** that doesn't close any `<ul>`.

---

Try to fix the errors first, because this could very well make the browser malfunction.

However, your footer should just be on the end of the document with a `position:static` CSS attribute. This will put it at th bottom of everything as long as it's a block

Comment: Thank you, I fixed errors, but with static position footer is right after slider, under rest of the content. I think I have a bad div construction, but  I have no idea how to fix it. Anyway thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
.main-wraper {
 min-height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 60px; /**footer height**/
}
.site-footer {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wraper">  
  <!--- Add Content Here -->  
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
 <!--- Add Footer Content Here -->
 <!--- I'm the Sticky Footer. -->  
</footer>
```

Comment: To make it sticky it requires `position:fixed` and you probably meant bottom:0, otherwise it's not a footer (it'll be positioned on the top). [Like in this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xfre9m0b/)

Comment: I tried this already (ofc with bottom:0), but the footer shows up in the middle of the page and there is a strange white square space right after the slider.